# Mobile device download fails

Tags: php, mobile

I have a curious problem:

I'm sending a video file (3gp) to the smartphones browser. Unfortunately the opening of the file fails with the message the media is corrupted. So i investigated my code and came up to the following:

I have a conditional state to check a variable. If I access this variable in the if-statement the download fails. If I only return true it works. So before the download I do a lot of checks. The last check looks like this:

```
private function Commit($transactionGuid)
{
    try
    {
        //Perform the commit process
        $result = $this->_client->Commit(array('TransactionGUID' => $transactionGuid, 'Service' => $this->_service));
    }
    catch (SoapFault $result)
    {
        //TODO: Provide some error handling
        return false;
    }

    $code = $result->CommitResult->Nr;

    return true /*($code == 0)*/;
}
```

As you can see the function performs a SOAP request. I looked up the result and everything is fine here. The request responds with a `CommitResult` object, which has the property Nr. This property gives an 0 if everything is fine. So if I run the code like above the download works. But if I say `return ($code == 0);` it fails on mobile devices (Blackberry, Android and IPhone).

Has anybody an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($result->CommitResult->Nr)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value of Nr is 0 and not "0"?  If it's returning it as a string that could be your problem.

Comment: I also checked that, the result of `var_dump($result->CommitResult->Nr)` is `int(0)`